# Spring Security : get the current user's fields from a database table

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I have a table in my database which contains such informations :

[image]

Nom = **name**.
Prénom = **firstname**.

---

I am trying, **once the user is logged in**, to retrieve **the whole user's fields**, besides : password.

So for instance,

If I type my username and my password on the logging page, **I would like to retrieve** :

- My name
- My firstname
- My email
- My username

---

Also,

I already know how to simply retrieve the username, however I'm stuck getting the mthe whole user's fields..

---

Here are my files,

**User Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter @Setter
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "nom", length = 50)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "prenom", length = 50)
    private String firstname;

    @Column(name = "username", length = 50, unique = true)
    private String username;

    @Column
    private String email;

    @Column
    private String role;

    @Column()
    private String password;
}
```

**AuthUserDetails | Custom UserDetails**

```
public class AuthUserDetails implements UserDetails {

    private final String name;
    private final String firstname;
    private final String username;
    private final String email;
    private final String password;

    private final List<GrantedAuthority> authorities;

    public AuthUserDetails(User user) {
        this.name = user.getUsername();
        this.firstname = user.getFirstname();
        this.username = user.getUsername();
        this.email = user.getEmail();
        this.password = user.getPassword();

        this.authorities = Arrays.stream(user.getRole().split(","))
                .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }


    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**AuthUserDetailsService | Custom UserDetailsService**

```
// Handle UserAuthentication from Database | Personal User's credentials
@Service
public class AuthUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

   private final UserRepository userRepository;

   @Autowired
    public AuthUserDetailsService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    // ************************ By | Username ************************ //
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        // Find the username in the DB
        Optional<User> user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

        user.orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Not found " + username));
        return user.map(AuthUserDetails::new).get();
        
    }
}
```

**UserService**

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private final JwtProvider jwtProvider;

    @Autowired
    public UserService(UserRepository userRepository, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder, 
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, JwtProvider jwtProvider) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.jwtProvider = jwtProvider;
    }

    // ****************************** Login ***************************** //

    public AuthenticationResponse login(AuthMapping authMapping) {
        Authentication authenticate = authenticationManager.authenticate(new 
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authMapping.getUsername(), authMapping.getPassword()));
        
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticate);
        
        String authenticationToken = jwtProvider.generateToken(authenticate);
        return new AuthenticationResponse(authenticationToken, authMapping.getUsername());
    }
 }
```

**AuthMapping** | This is what the user types to log in

```
@Getter @Setter
public class AuthMapping {
    private String username;
    private String password;
}
```

**AuthenticationResponse** | This is what is retrieved once we are successfully logged in

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AuthenticationResponse {
    private String authenticationToken;
    private String username;
}
```

**SecurityConfig**

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    // *************************************************************************** //

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;


    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(@Qualifier("authUserDetailsService") UserDetailsService userDetailsService, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder, JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
        this.jwtAuthenticationFilter = jwtAuthenticationFilter;
    }


    // *************************************************************************** //

    // Authorization
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/users/register").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/users/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
        // JWT Authentication
        http.addFilterBefore(this.jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        // CORS
        http.addFilterBefore(new CorsFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class);
    }

    // *************************************************************************** //

    /**
     * Handle The Authentication in Spring | InMemory/LDAP/JDBC
     * The handle is made through a service : UserDetailsService
     */
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(this.passwordEncoder);
        /*
         * Read user from the database
         * Spring needs to decode the password before performing the authentication
         */
    }

    // *************************************************************************** //
    
    @Bean(BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    @Override
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManager();
    }
```

**UserController | Login**

```
// User | Login
@PostMapping("/login")
public AuthenticationResponse login(@RequestBody AuthMapping authMapping) {
    return userService.login(authMapping);
}
```

---

How to solve it please?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write another custom method for retrieve your result:
I present my piece of code written in Kotlin.

```
    fun currentUser(): UserDto {
        val auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication
    
//auth.principal this is username
    
        val optional = repository.findByEmail(auth.principal.toString())
        if (!optional.isPresent) throw ErrorWithUserTokenException(auth.principal.toString())
        return UserDto.toDto(optional.get())
    }

    data class UserDto(
            var id: Long,
            var username: String
     
    ) {
        companion object {
            fun toDto(user: User): UserDto {
                return user.run { UserDto(id!!, username) }
            }
        }
    }
```

I think that at least, this answer gives you an idea for resolving your problem:)

Comment: OK. God luck! I'm happy if my answer is useful for you! @Finalmix6